# OneNote URLs are broken in Big Sur. How can I open them again?

Tags: url, terminal, scripting, onenote, macos-big-sur

Commands like this to programmatically open OneNote URLs are no longer working on Big Sur:

```
open "/Applications/Microsoft OneNote.app" "onenote:#section-id=146934FE-14A8-0000-0000-EFB650ABCDEF&end"
```

I imagine this is an issue with accessing other apps as well.  How can I get these working again?

This is the error message I'm seeing:

> `The file /Applications/Microsoft OneNote.app/onenote:#section-id={94EC1215-0000-0000-B2FE-DAE4868CA1F0} does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work I just **removed the curly braces**.  It looks like Big Sur works differently when it comes to URL encoding.  This command works:

```
open "/Applications/Microsoft OneNote.app" "onenote:#section-id=146934FE-14A8-0000-0000-EFB650ABCDEF&end"
```